# Auto-generating attributes

Tags: core-data

I'am designing a new invoicing application. There are a number of features that I don't know how to implement in Core Data. I ask you for help with the following.

To keep things simple assume that there are 2 entities, Invoice entity and Detail entity with to-many relationship 'invoiceDetails' and to-one relationship 'detailInvoice'.  Here are my questions.

1. Detail entity should have attribute 'sequenceNumber' which should be auto-generated when the user adds new detail. For each invoice the sequenceNumber should start at 1 and be incremented as the user adds new details. The sequenceNumber should be used to sort details within their invoice.
2. Detail entity has also attributes 'numberOfItems' and 'price'. It also should have attribute 'amount' which should be auto-generated as product of numberOfItems and price.
3. Invoice entity should have attribute 'netAmount' which should be generated as the sum of all detail amounts.
4. Invoice entity should have attribute 'vat' which should be auto-generated as an expression from netAmount.
5. Invoice entity should also have attribute 'totalAmount' auto-generated as a sum of netAmount and vat.
6. Invoice entity should have attribute 'dueTo' auto-generated from current date plus some number of days.

How do I accomplish this in Core Data application? Thanks.

/Mikael

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Detail entity should have attribute 'sequenceNumber' which should be auto-generated when the user adds new detail.

You'll have to assign this value yourself. What I'd do is store the highest sequence number as metadata on the persistent store file (see `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`'s metadata-related methods). Any time you create a new instance, read the highest number from the store metadata, increment it, use that value on the new instance, and then save the new value back to store metadat.

> 2-6. Calculated attributes

These are generally handled by subclassing `NSManagedObject` and then overriding the setter methods on attributes whose value affects other attributes. For example, based on #2, the setter for your `price` attribute would look something like:

```
- (void)setPrice:(NSDecimalNumber *)price
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"price"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:price forKey:price];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"price"];

    // Now calculate the new value for "amount" and set it on self.
}
```

Follow the same pattern for each case. You can also use key-value observing to watch for changes on these attributes, but I find custom accessors to be clearer and less error-prone.

Comment: Many thanks Tom. I think I need to store highest sequence number with Invoice because each invoice requires new detail series. BTW, what is the difference between setPrimitiveValue and setValue?

Comment: The difference is that `setPrimitiveValue` just sets the new value, without implicitly calling any other setter methods and without triggering any KVO notifications. If you override a setter method, you need to use it to avoid making a recursive call to the method you're already in.

Comment: If I have attribute 'price' in my entity and implement 'setPrice' as you have shown then why not use self->price = ... instead of setPrimitiveValue:price...? Does setPrimitiveValue update both the 'price' attribute and my own private primitivePrice varaible if I have one? Thanks.

Comment: Because, one should never change the ivar directly via `->` syntax unless you're absolutely sure that the method you could be using isn't doing something besides change the accessor. I suspect that using direct access would screw up Core Data's change monitoring and lead to lost data.